# XML input for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch data from xml in stored procedure, but it returns null for every record please help!!

Below is my script I used in Stored Procedure to fetch records:

```
declare @deviceData xml
set @deviceData = 
'<result>
   <resultTotalRows>24</resultTotalRows>
   <requestedStartRow>0</requestedStartRow>
   <resultSize>24</resultSize>
   <requestedSize>1000</requestedSize>
   <remainingSize>0</remainingSize>
   <DiaChannelDataHistoryFull>
      <id>
         <devConnectwareId>00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF521221</devConnectwareId>
         <ddInstanceName>bpcuff1</ddInstanceName>
         <dcChannelName>diastolic</dcChannelName>
         <dcdhId>549747901</dcdhId>
      </id>
      <cstId>6423</cstId>
      <xpExtAddr>00:13:A2:00:40:6B:95:43</xpExtAddr>
      <dcDataType>0</dcDataType>
      <dcdUpdateTime>2012-07-31T20:53:44.000Z</dcdUpdateTime>
      <dcdStringValue>82</dcdStringValue>
      <dcdIntegerValue>82</dcdIntegerValue>
   </DiaChannelDataHistoryFull>
</result>'

declare @xmltable table (PatientID int, GatewayId nvarchar(255), DeviceName nvarchar(255), TimeStamp datetime, Systolic int, Diastolic int, Pulse int, Status nvarchar(255))
insert into @xmltable (PatientID, GatewayId, DeviceName, TimeStamp, Systolic, Diastolic, Pulse, Status)
select
1 as PatientID,
tbl.clms.value('@devConnectwareId','nvarchar(255)') as GatewayId,
tbl.clms.value('@ddInstanceName','nvarchar(255)') as DeviceName,
tbl.clms.value('@dcdUpdateTime','datetime') as TimeStamp,
case tbl.clms.value('@dcChannelName','nvarchar(255)') when 'Systolic' then tbl.clms.value('@dcdStringValue','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Systolic,
case tbl.clms.value('@dcChannelName','nvarchar(255)') when 'Diastolic' then tbl.clms.value('@dcdStringValue','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Diastolic,
case tbl.clms.value('@dcChannelName','nvarchar(255)') when 'Pulse' then tbl.clms.value('@dcdStringValue','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Pulse,
case tbl.clms.value('@dcChannelName','nvarchar(255)') when 'Sample_Status' then tbl.clms.value('@dcdStringValue','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Status
from @deviceData.nodes('/result/DiaChannelDataHistoryFull') tbl(clms)

select * from @xmltable
```

Comment: All the values that you are retrieving are in the <id> node under result/DiaChannelDataHistoryFull. So I would expect that you should be specifying from @deviceData.nodes('/result/DiaChannelDataHistoryFull/id') tbl(clms)

Comment: No, some values are from <id> and other from <DiaChannelDataHistoryFull> itself, as dcdStringValue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@` is for attributes not node values and you have to give the path to the `id` node for the values that is in there.

```
select
1 as PatientID,        
tbl.clms.value('(id/devConnectwareId)[1]','nvarchar(255)') as GatewayId,
tbl.clms.value('(id/ddInstanceName)[1]','nvarchar(255)') as DeviceName,
tbl.clms.value('dcdUpdateTime[1]','datetime') as TimeStamp,
case tbl.clms.value('(id/dcChannelName)[1]','nvarchar(255)') when 'Systolic' then tbl.clms.value('dcdStringValue[1]','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Systolic,
case tbl.clms.value('(id/dcChannelName)[1]','nvarchar(255)') when 'Diastolic' then tbl.clms.value('dcdStringValue[1]','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Diastolic,
case tbl.clms.value('(id/dcChannelName)[1]','nvarchar(255)') when 'Pulse' then tbl.clms.value('dcdStringValue[1]','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Pulse,
case tbl.clms.value('(id/dcChannelName)[1]','nvarchar(255)') when 'Sample_Status' then tbl.clms.value('dcdStringValue[1]','nvarchar(255)') else null end as Status
from @deviceData.nodes('/result/DiaChannelDataHistoryFull') tbl(clms)
```